Switching languages turns off Caps Lock
I currently have 2 languages as my input source. If I type in one language with Caps Lock turned on and then switch to another language (using Control-Space) Caps Lock turns off for some reason. I would like it to be on in such case, just like on my Linux machine. Can this be configured in MacOS?
